# "Slick in the eye"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request, phrases

Is there such phrase in English as "slick in the eye" to have the meaning as "directly to the eye"?

For example:

"A glass bead hit him right in the eye." or

"A glass bead hit him slick in the eye."

Answer (score 2):

Using “slick” in that context would confuse most English speakers, and I suspect few if any would guess that the intended meaning was “directly”.

Slang uses of “slick” could, at a stretch, make it work, but the meaning would be something like “cleanly” or “efficiently”, or even “impressively”. However, that is, as I say, a stretch.

So, no, there is no such English phrase as, “slick in the eye”.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can come up with is "[smack-dab](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smack-dab)"

> A glass bead hit him *smack-dab* in the eye

I have never heard "slick in the eye"